# TryGetObjectByKey not compiling in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following code that does a great job at saving a detached object in a .Net 4 / EF 4 project.  I wanted to use that code in a new .Net 4.5 / EF 5 project.  I copied it in and now it gives me a compile error of:

"MyEntities does not contain a definition for 'TryGetObjectByKey' and no extension method 'TryGetObjectByKey' accepting a first argument of type MyEntities could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Allegedly it is in the System.Data.Objects namespace (so I have a using for it) from the System.Data.Entity assembly (.dll) which is referenced.

```
public bool UpdateChanged(IEntityWithKey DetachedObject = null) {
    bool Result = false;

    try {
        using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities()) {
            if (DetachedObject != null) {
                object Original = null;

                if (db.TryGetObjectByKey(DetachedObject.EntityKey, out Original))
                    db.ApplyCurrentValues(DetachedObject.EntityKey.EntitySetName, DetachedObject);
            } // if they want to Update an Entity

            db.SaveChanges();
            Result = true;
        } // using the database
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } // try-catch

    return Result;
} // UpdateChanged - Method
```

According to this link it should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738728.aspx

Can you please help?

**UPDATE / SOLUTION:**

Based on @Rowan's answer below I have simply modified my Save method to something like the following instead of creating an UpdateChanged method that takes Detached objects:

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities()) {
    if (o.ID > 0) {
        // Existing Owner
        db.Owners.Attach(o);
        db.Entry(o).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(o.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } else {
        // New Owner
        db.Owners.Add(o);
    } // if this is a New Owner

    db.SaveChanges();
} // using the database
```

Comment: Is `MyEntities` a subclass of `ObjectContext`?

Comment: `MyEntities` (the type of `db`) is seen as the first argument, so this looks like an extension method you've got somewhere.

Comment: To make Brian's question more clear - is MyEntities derived from ObjectContext or DbContext? Can you show how it looks like?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, MyEntities is derived from DbContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TryGetObjectByKey is a method on ObjectContext. Starting in Visual Studio 2012 new models will generate a DbContext based context by default (DbContext is designed to be a simpler and more intuitive API surface). Existing models will keep generating ObjectContext unless you choose to swap to DbContext. You can also [revert back to ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581) for new models.

You can always get at the underlying ObjectContext using ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(...).

Comment: Thank you @Rowan, that did the trick.  With this new DbContext, is there a better/different way to connect an disconnected object?